NextJS Server actions + react-hook-form <Controller>. Empty payload on submit
Task: Connect GoogleSpreadsheet API to my NextJS 14^ app router app as a database.
Previously, I did it with api/route.ts (Next 13.2), but today I learned about NextJs server actions, they are already stable and recommended to be used in such cases.
Many tutorials e.g. "Next Server actions + react-hook-form" show a plain form, without nesting or uncontrolled components. In my case, I have to use  to control nested component.
Everything looks good until I submit a form. I placed log to see what I submit. So my log looks like:
Server action is running FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [
    { name: '$ACTION_REF_1', value: '' },
    {
      name: '$ACTION_1:0',
      value: '{"id":"2204ae4db6ac83481a9742d570e84d17e6598884","bound":"$@1"}'
    },
    { name: '$ACTION_1:1', value: '[null]' },
    { name: '$ACTION_KEY', value: 'k2943444782' }
  ]
}

But it should be like this:
[Symbol(state)]: [ { name: 'email', value: 'lol@lol.com' } ]

In result I catch an error, because the payload is empty
Disclaimer: I know that it looks like non-sense to wrap input inside Controller, but it serves as an example, it has to work too.
As a code reference:
HeroForm.tsx
"use client";
import { State, postToSpreadSheet } from "@/src/app/actions";
import { formSchema } from "@/src/app/validation";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { FieldPath, FormProvider, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { FormContent } from "./components/FormContent";

export type Schema = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

export const HeroForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState<State, FormData>(
    postToSpreadSheet,
    null
  );

  const router = useRouter();

  const formMethods = useForm<Schema>({
    mode: "all",
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
    },
  });

  const { setError, reset } = formMethods;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) return;

    if (state.status === "error") {
      console.log(state.errors);
      state.errors?.forEach((error) => {
        setError(error.path as FieldPath<Schema>, {
          message: error.message,
        });
      });
    }

    if (state.status === "success") {
      alert("Success!");
      reset();
      router.push("/success");
    }
  }, [reset, router, setError, state]);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
      <form action={formAction}>
        <FormContent />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

FormContent.tsx
import { Button } from "@components/_common/atoms";
import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import styles from "./FormContent.module.scss";
import { TextInputField } from "./TextInputField";

export const FormContent = () => {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <TextInputField
        name="email"
        placeholder="Enter Email"
        isLoading={pending}
      />
      <Button customStyle={styles.button} disabled={pending} isSubmit>
        Notify me
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};


TextInputField.tsx
import { Icon } from "@components/_common/atoms";
import { faSpinner } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { combineClasses } from "@utils";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import styles from "./TextInputField.module.scss";

type EmailInput = {
  email: string;
};

interface Props {
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  isLoading?: boolean;
}

export const TextInputField: React.FC<Props> = ({ placeholder, isLoading }) => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

  const { control } = useFormContext<EmailInput>();

  return (
    <Controller
      name="email"
      defaultValue=""
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <div
            className={combineClasses(
              styles.field,
              isFocused && styles.focus,
              error && styles.error
            )}
          >
            <input
              type="email"
              value={value}
              onChange={(value) => {
                onChange(value);
                console.log(value);
              }}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              className={styles.input}
              onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
              onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
            />
            {isLoading && <Icon icon={faSpinner} spin />}
          </div>
          {error && <p className={styles.message}>{error.message}</p>}
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
};


actions.ts
"use server";

import { getEmailSpecs } from "@services";
import { google } from "googleapis";
import { ZodError } from "zod";
import { formSchema } from "./validation";

export type State =
  | {
      status: "success";
      message: string;
    }
  | {
      status: "error";
      message: string;
      errors?: Array<{
        path: string;
        message: string;
      }>;
    }
  | null;

export async function postToSpreadSheet(
  prevState: State | null,
  data: FormData
): Promise<State> {
  /**TEST */
  console.log("Server action is running", data);

  try {
    const { email } = formSchema.parse(data);

    if (!email) {
      return {
        status: "error",
        message: "Please try again. If the problem persists, contact us.",
      };
    }

    const emailSpecs = await getEmailSpecs(email as string);

    if (emailSpecs.result !== "deliverable") {
      return {
        status: "error",
        message: "Oops, please try another email",
      };
    }

    /* GOOGLE AUTH and Spreadsheet POST*/


    return {
      status: "success",
      message: "Data was successfully posted",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ZodError) {
      return {
        status: "error",
        message: "Invalid form data.",
        errors: error.issues.map((issue) => ({
          path: issue.path.join("."),
          message: `Server validation: ${issue.message}`,
        })),
      };
    }
    return {
      status: "error",
      message: "Something went wrong. Please try again.",
    };
  }
}


I've searched through the react-hook-form repository and the Internet but didn't find such a case.
With plain form with registered fields (<input {...registered("name")}/>) it works very well. But I have to understand what is a problem here. Is it  does something under the hood and is not ready for Server actions feature, I don't know.
My Goal: receive payload and POST it through the Server action.
I really appreciate your help!

It's very hard to understand your error make description short while posting like this, so everyone can read

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

Inside of the TextInputField have you tried deleting all of those methods controlling the input and just spreading the field on the component?
<Controller
      name="email"
      defaultValue=""
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <div
            className={combineClasses(
              styles.field,
              isFocused && styles.focus,
              error && styles.error
            )}
          >
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder={placeholder}
              className={styles.input}
              {...field}
            />
            {isLoading && <Icon icon={faSpinner} spin />}
          </div>
          {error && <p className={styles.message}>{error.message}</p>}
        </div>
      )}
    />

